# Calling a query from VB

Tags: ms-access, vba

Im trying to call a query in Access from VB but am having some problems. Here's the code:

```
 Dim myQuery As QueryDefs
 myQuery("2012Patient_q").Execute
```

But this doesn't work. I tried googling it but to no avail. What am i missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Visual Basic for Applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should probably read like this:

```
Dim myQuery As QueryDef        ' no "s"
Set myQuery = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("2012Patient_q")
myQuery.Execute
```

Or, simply put without any intermediate variables:

```
CurrentDB.QueryDefs("2012Patient_q").Execute
```

Comment: It all depends on whether it is a select or action query.

Comment: its saying "Cannot execute a select query"? The actual query in question is a select query though...

Comment: @Katana24 Then you cannot execute it. You can open it or assign it to a recordset. Say what you want to do next.

Comment: If you are wanting to process the query with some vba code, use the openrecordset method. If you want to just open and view the query, use the openquery method. You should use the .execute method for update or delete queries only.

Comment: In the case of an `Action` query, there's no need to refer to the `QueryDefs` collection, you can simply `CurrentDb.Execute("qryName")`